# JMeter jp@gc-WebDriver Sampler — Run the Webpage from CSV File

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have tried to created the Login from the CSV file with CSV Dataset Config. But Not sure why it's not picking the variable and it's entered the wordings with "Username" & "Password" on the Login Page. Can you please advise?

`import org.openqa.selenium.*;`
`import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;`
`import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;`
`WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();`
`WDS.browser.get("https://uat-testing.com/"    );`
`sleep(5000);`
`var Username = WDS.vars.get("username" );`
`var Password = WDS.vars.get("password" );`
`WDS.log.info('Username' + Username );`
`WDS.log.info('Password' + Password );`
`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@type='text']"  )).sendKeys("Username" );`
`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@type='password']"  )).clear();`
`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@type='password']"  )).sendKeys("Password" );`
`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//button/span" )).click();`
`sleep(10000);`
`WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove quotation marks from these lines:

```
sendKeys("Username" )
```

and

```
sendKeys("Password" );
```

so they would look like:

```
sendKeys(Username)
```

and

```
sendKeys("Password" );
```

---

Also using [`sleep` function is a performance anti-pattern](https://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program/), I would rather recommend using [Explicit Wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) so your test would proceed as soon as the condition will be met rather than forcing the flow to sleep for 10 seconds, see [5 Ways to Test AJAX Calls in Selenium WebDriver](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/five-ways-to-test-ajax-calls-with-selenium-webdriver) for more information.